# jQuery: Dynamically Adding Glyphicon

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a slight functioning issue in Firefox w/ a jQuery glyphicon.  I used Bootstrap to build my portfolio and used jQuery `.load` function to load some portfolio pages dynamically when you click on them.

I also added a jQuery `.append` function to append a glyphicon close icon on each opened page, but when you open and close them on my page in the portfolio section it keeps adding multiple glyphicons. It adds more and more as you open and close.

What is happening here? Can anyone help?

MY CODE:

```
$(".close").append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>');
$(".glyphicon-remove-circle").click(function(e) {
    $(".portfolioContent").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-remove-circle',function(){
   $(".portfolioContent").fadeOut();
});
```

Or this way too:

```
$('.close').on('click','.glyphicon-remove-circle',function(){
   $(".portfolioContent").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Yes, since it is dynamic content, you should use it this way...the second way should works too.

Comment: Okay, it worked!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was fighting with this for hours yesterday

Comment: I have one more issue.  The navbar at the top is suppose to scroll when clicking on a link, but it doesn't do it anymore after I added the code.  Did it mess something up here?

Comment: Can you post your nav code, so i can help you...or you can open another question and post the link here....

Comment: //jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

Comment: <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

Comment: The body tag is connected to the navbar

Comment: Ok so the issue is that its flickering instead of highlighting the correct link.  Sorry, I got the navbar to work when scrolling, but now its flickering.  Not sure whats happening.

Comment: Can you reproduce your code issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/ ..do not forget to save it and post the generated link